# what does @api in doctype promise

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

I'm working on fixing a core bug so that I can do a pull request... for this I'm adding new exception type...

```
<?php
/**
 * AfterCommitException Exception
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Framework\Exception;

/**
 * @api
 */
class AfterCommitException extends \Exception
{
}
```

following the style of the other exceptions there is an `@api` in the doctype..

1. What is this promising?
2. What do I need to do to fulfil that promise?

Comment: It may be some exception which can be thrown by the API area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@api` tag indicates the code is part of the public API and is subject to the [Magento Backward Compatibility](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/versioning/dependencies.html) Policy.

The `@api` tag can be applied to `a constant`, `a method`, or to the entire `class/interface.` If the `@api` tag is applied at the file level, then all methods within the file are part of the public `API`. You do not need to annotate each method individually.

Source: [Magento DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/docblock-standard-general.html#api)